# Collection was modified after the enumerator was instantiated

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm-light

I'm having a bit of a problem with a ListView that is bound to a class that is based on ICollection and where i store my data in a LinkedList.

```
public class CircularList<T> : ICollection<T>
{
    private readonly LinkedList<T> list;

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.list.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    // more code..
}
```

When I jump to the screen where this is shown, I get the message: A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll
Additional information: Collection was modified after the enumerator was instantiated.

However, if I press continue, the list is shown without a problem. The last entry I added is in there. I know it is allready in there before going to that screen, because i also bind to a field in the bottom of my app where i show the last added entry from that Linkedlist. Also, when i go to that screen a second time without adding new entry's into the list no warnings pop up.

Could it be that I have to refresh the IEnumerator before jumping to that screen (or when adding an item to the list), and if so, how? Or could it be something completely else?

I already checked that there are no additions or deletions from the list when the list is being shown on screen.